# is there anything like this web browser in the debian/ubuntu repositories?

Tags: software-rec, browser, web

It's been a while since my web-browsing has really suited me.

What I would really like is:

A javascript-enabled web browser with a tab-based browsing system that can be controlled simultaneously using a console and a GUI.

For example, I'd like to be able to...

1) open a bunch of tabs

2) go to the console and tell it something like 'copy the url open in each tab and write it, along with the html, to a file, for each open tab'

in other words, I want to be able to browse with tabs at my leisure, and then write scripts that iterate over each tab. Does anything like that exist?

Comment: Would Firefox with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) fit the bill?

Comment: @Gilles I haven't tried it, but based on what I've seen, I don't think so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that [`uzbl`](http://uzbl.org/) is just the right ninja magic for this. It is a scriptable, console-controllable single-purpose browser. Being based on webkit, its rendering and javascript support is first class, but it follows the unix phylosophy of doing one thing and doing it well while allowing other programs to push data in and out.

There is a wrapper for it that adds support for a tab-like interface as well.

Comment: wow, that sounds like just what i was after... i'm going to try it out now! thanks.

Comment: thank you. 'the right ninja magic' would be an understatement -- that is totally just what i was after... i'm already deep into the readme file, and will probably bore everyone around me by talking too much about this wonderful browser.

Comment: @ixtmixilix: Have fun. I still remember the exuberant "where have you been all my life" when I first discovered that one. As time wore on and other browsers got better I find I use it less than I expected, but it's still a fantastic ace in the whole for some applications.